# display the json data returned from controller to cshtml page on page load

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller method which return json data,

```
public JsonResult GetByKey(int? id)
        {           
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error! Please contact Administrator..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                var data = (from z in db.FirmModels
                            where z.FirmId == id
                            select z).ToList();

                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
        }
```

It will return only single row. I have to display this data in the view page, but I do not know how can I do this?

cshtml page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Details";
}

<div class="d-flex p-2">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="text" id="i_nimitta" class="myDivClass" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="c_nimitta" />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div >
    <div id="lbl_firmName" style="display:inline;"></div>
    <div id="lbl_ownerName" style="display:inline;"></div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("FirmModels/GetByKey",
            function (json) {
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    $('#lbl_firmName').html(json[i].firmName);
                    $('#lbl_ownerName').html(json[i].ownerName);
                }
            });
    });
  
</script>
```

In many of the solutions I found that the json is shown in tabular form inside a table but I need to display the data in paragraph wise.  Like:

```
<div id="d_firmContent">
This firm <div id="lbl_firmName" style="display:inline;"></div> belongs to Mr./Mrs. <div id="lbl_ownerName" style="display:inline;"></div>
//similarly other set of data from json
</div>
```

So, how can I do this? **I am only getting raw json data**, the view page is not displaying why?

Json output

```
[{"FirmId":2,"FirmName":"Jeenat Travels","PropName":"Jeenat Harpa","PropAddress":"HP","PropContact":"5345345345345","PropCitizenshipNum":"5345345345","Email":"","CapitalAmount":"10000",}]
```

I kept alert in the `function (json)` but it is also not working, it seems that the page is not redirecting to cshtml page, only raw json file is output by the controller. But I am not sure, what is the issue. local host url *https://localhost:44334/FirmModels/GetByKey/2*

Comment: I dont know how your db.FirmModels but i would guess that since you are filtering by ID, only one result comes out?

Comment: @Dementic Yes, I have mentioned in the post only single row, but now how to display that json data in view page.

Comment: You keep overwriting the results $('#lbl_firmName').html(json[i].firmName); will keep writing the Next result to the same div.
You should instead be creating new rows.

Comment: @Dementic I have to display the json data in paragraph format, not tabular form. But how can I do it? I am getting raw json data as output. Please help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery JSON to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804995/jquery-json-to-table)

Comment: @Dementic I have added description, please check.

Comment: Can you share the json output ?

Comment: @Dementic added the output... Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

The proeprty should be Pascal cased: `FirmName` and not `firmName`,
As per the OwnerName, it does not seem to be included in the json and therfor would not be set.
Please note i have inlined the Json, but it should work also with your example, the main issue is the casing of the property name.

```js
var json = [{
  "FirmId": 2,
  "FirmName": "Jeenat Travels",
  "PropName": "Jeenat Harpa",
  "PropAddress": "HP",
  "PropContact": "5345345345345",
  "PropCitizenshipNum": "5345345345",
  "Email": "",
  "CapitalAmount": "10000",
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lbl_firmName').html(json[0].FirmName);
    $('#lbl_ownerName').html(json[0].OwnerName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="d_firmContent">
  This firm
  <div id="lbl_firmName" style="display:inline;"></div> belongs to Mr./Mrs.
  <div id="lbl_ownerName" style="display:inline;"></div>
</div>
```